# Suffrage abuse?

Tags: discussion, abuse, voting-badges

Just noticed all new questions on SO getting a single up-vote each.

That looks rather suspicious - all upvoted within seconds of each other.

Is someone trying to achieve the [Suffrage badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage) without looking at the merit of each question?

Here are some of the upvoted questions:

- [UIButton in UITableViewCell events not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635453/uibutton-in-uitableviewcell-events-not-working)
- [Vim Eclipse colorscheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635461/vim-eclipse-colorscheme)
- [Check if Rhythmbox is running via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635462/check-if-rhythmbox-is-running-via-python)

Comment: Try the Electorate badge

Comment: @random - fair point. Still, I would call this misuse.

Comment: @Oded hmm, maybe it's abuse, but there probably isn't much that can be done about it. It's hard to tell a frivolous question vote from a "real" one

Comment: This problem is definitely as old as the Electorate badge.  Suffrage amounts to at most one day and 30 votes of abuse; Electorate is 20 days and 600 votes.

Comment: @Aarobot yeah. The Electorate badge is a bad one anyway because of the "25% of votes must be on questions" mandate. That really sucks.

Comment: @Pekka: I just don't vote for answers on any new sites, unless it's either *really* bad or *really* good.

Comment: Surely seeing multiple upvotes in a very short timespan is an indication of this phenomenon?

Comment: @Aarobot [Great plan](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

Comment: Perhaps increase the time limit between voting on two questions? I can't think of myself legitimately voting on two separate questions within a few seconds.

Comment: Now as a dev you can dig in the old data and find out yourself. :D

Answer (score 3):

That's a rather **bold assumption** you're assuming here :

> Is someone trying to achieve Suffrage without looking at the merit of
>   each question?

What's to say that s/he isn't trying to achieve the [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badge?

Users can vote however they like. It's their vote. Although it's definitely strongly recommended to vote on the quality of the post itself, there is nothing to stop a user from voting based on the direction of the wind that day.

Comment: I'll upvote this, even though I think you may have only answered for a revival / necromancer badge ;)

Comment: @PeterJ What about the Enlightened badge?

Comment: -1 the wind is definitely blowing east here today.

Comment: @PeterJ upvoted your comment,  even though I suspect you only commented to get the Pundit badge :-)